# Unable to upload byte array image to fire-storage using firebase functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am unable to upload a image file which is in byte array format to the firestore using cloud functions. The below code is working fine in local with **app.listen()** but when I am trying with **exports** function its not working

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId ='<project-Id>';

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage({
projectId: projectId,
keyFilename: '<>'
});


const bucket = storage.bucket("<bucket-name>");

// Byte aray to Image 

function saveImage(filename, data) {
console.log("inside saveImage", data.length);
var myBuffer = new Buffer.alloc(data.length);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    myBuffer[i] = data[i];
}
console.log(myBuffer)
fs.createWriteStream(filename, myBuffer, 'binary', function (err) {
    console.log("inside writeFile");
    if (err) {
        console.log('error inside fs', err);
    } else {
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }
 });
}

saveImage("image1.png", result);


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});



exports.UploadImage = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Can someone please help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reading around image upload into firebase storage. I realized that instead of converting byte array into Image, we can directly upload byte array using  **Uint8Array()** which automatically converts it into image and upload into firebase storage. Below is the modified code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId ='<project-Id>';

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage({

    projectId: projectId,
    keyFilename: './servicekey.json'
});


const bucket = storage.bucket("<bucket-name>");

const options = {
    action: 'read',
    expires: '03-17-2025'
};

// storing Byte array

function saveImage(filename, data) {

 var imageBuffer = new Uint8Array(data);
 var file = bucket.file(filename);

 file.save(imageBuffer, {
           metadata: { contentType: 'image/png' },
           }, 
           ((error) => {

           if (error) {
              console.log('error')
           }
        file.getSignedUrl(options)
        .then(results => {
            const url = results[0];
            console.log(`The signed url for ${imageName} is ${url}.`);
        })
 }));

}

saveImage("image1.png", <byte-Array as input>);


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
 Content-Type, Accept");
 next();
});



exports.UploadImage = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Can the reverse be done; where the image is stored in Firebase Storage and get it downloaded to an image on an html page?

Comment: @Learn2Code, where you able to do it??download the image to a HITML file?

Comment: @Jasmine yes, but the issue was that gmail blocks it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I ended up when uploading files into **Firebase Storage** using the **Firebase Functions** and **Google Cloud Pub/Sub**.

> **NOTE** Pub/Sub is optional and only worked for my use case

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

function saveImage(filename, data) {
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
    const imageBuffer = new Uint8Array(data);
    const file = bucket.file(`optional_sub_directory/${filename}`, {
        uploadType: {resumable: false}
    });

    file.save(imageBuffer, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(`Error uploading: ${filename} with message: ${err.message}`);
            return;
        }

        console.log('Uploaded file');
    });
}

exports.helloPubSub = functions.pubsub
    .topic('demo-topic')
    .onPublish(async(message) => {
        /**
         *  Here goes code to extract the file buffer
         */

        const buffer = /** buffer */

        saveImage("stack_overflow.txt", buffer);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your responses. I used the same approach but I have two problems. First one is I don't get response  when the function is run although the image is being uploaded. And the other problem is I can not see the image after downloading and also on **Firebase** page. I have set the **ContentType** to **'image/jpg'**.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

  try {
    const imageBuffer = new Uint8Array(req.rawBody);
    const file = bucket.file(`projects/sample.jpg`);

    file.save(
      imageBuffer,
      { resumable: false, metadata: { contentType: "image/jpg" } },
      err => {
        if (err) {
          throw new Error(err);
        }
        res.send({
          success: true,
          message: "File Successfully Uploaded..."
        });
      }
    );

  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
```

Comment: Is req.rawBody a byteArray or base64 ? If it is byteArray then use Unit8array() otherwise directly you can pass req.rawBody as a imageBuffer